# Latent heat of solidification

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

What is the heat release mechanism involved in solidification from liquid phase? Is the energy transferred to nucleation centres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heat is simply released to the surroundings during freezing. Freezing occurs because at a temperature below the freezing point, solid has a lower Gibbs free energy than liquid. The plots of G vs T is [mathematically derived](http://staff.um.edu.mt/jgri1/teaching/che2372/notes/04/g_props/g_props.html).

At the freezing point, $G_{solid} = G_{liquid}$ There is no change in Gibbs free energy in a reversible freezing process. Therefore, $$H_{solid} -
T S_{solid}= H_{liquid} -TS_{liquid}$$.
$$\Delta{H}_{freezing} = T\Delta{S_{freezing}}$$

In other words, the decrease in enthalpy in a freezing process is used to overcome the decrease in entropy when a liquid freezes into an ordered solid.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So is heat radiated away from the solid via infrared photons?

Comment: I believe heat is simply removed via convection/conduction (i.e. when an ice cube melts, the air immediately surrounding it is cooled because it supplies heat for the melting process).